# Azure cloud deployment fails : Certificate with thumbprint was not found

Tags: azure, deployment

I am developing a Web API based web service to be hosted on Azure. I am using Azure 1.8 SDK.
When I try to deploy my cloud service, it takes a very long time to upload after which I get an error message which says:

```
12:09:52 PM - Error: The certificate with thumbprint d22e9de125640c48a4f83de06ae6069f09cfb76c was not found.  Http Status Code: BadRequest  OperationId: 50daf49111c9487f82f3be09763e7924
12:09:53 PM - Deployment failed with a fatal error
```

Apparently, the certificate being referred to is related to enabling remote desktop to role instances on the cloud (i am not very sure about this; saw this on the internet for a similar problem). However,  I did not check the option to enable remote desktop on the instances while publishing.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The certificate used in your project doesn't exist on the cloud environment. Make sure the same certificate used by your project is uploaded to the cloud environment. If you are using Visual Studio then you can fix this error as follows:

1. Right click your Web Role / Worker Role (under Roles folder in the cloud project) → Properties → Certificates
2. Click on the ellipsis button under Thumbprint which will point to your certificate.
3. Upload the certificate which shown here to Windows Azure environment (Production or Staging)

Comment: There is no certificate at my projects webrole. Should I add a new one ?

Answer (score 36):

What worked for me was:

1. Goto powershell and type mmc
2. Add certificates snap-in by going to File > Add/Remove Snap-in > Choose Certificates from the list > Choose My user Account
3. Right click on Certificates - Current User and select Find Certificates
4. On the dialog box, set Contains to 'azure' and Look in Field to 'Issued To'
5. Press Find Now. You should be able to see a list of certificates.
6. Check for the thumbprint by double-clicking the certificate > Details tab > scroll down to Thumbprint
7. Once you found your certificate, close the dialog, Right click and select Export
8. Select to export the private key. Follow the steps until you have a *pfx file for upload to Azure
9. Goto your service and select the Certificates tab
10. Click Upload, select the exported *pfx file, and supply the password you've set during export
11. Goto Dashbord and update the Cloud package
12. List item

Comment: how complicated can it be.... how did I select this accidentially? My first deployment worked without doing this

Comment: Mine started doing this all of a sudden but this fixed it - quite straightforward in the end.

Comment: Nice tutorial, it got me hoping for a few minutes. Then I crashed in to Certificate Export Wizard, that stopped me by in-ability to export to pfx.

Comment: You can also paste the thumbprint into `Contains` and then set the Look in Field to `SHA1 Hash` and it will limit the list to the ones with the given thumbprint.

Comment: If I don't have any certificates how do I make one?  I am using azure and I have deployed to a different environment than the one I am trying to do right now so it seems like I must have a certificate somewhere but I don't know where to start.  On step 5 of this answer it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

have you uploaded your publishing settings file in visual studio and/or a management certificate? this is crucial to be a trusted point by your azure subscription, hence why you could be having this issue. BTW try upgrading to SDK 2.1 too for better support and better features (if possible of course).

Comment: How is this done? Could you please elaborate? I am new to Azure..it appears that I need a .pfx or a .cer file which needs to be uploaded..but I could  not find this file anywhere in my solution

Comment: you can achieve this by either going to this link https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx or by using the powershell command Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile once you have this you can then use this file to start the publshing wizard in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Arbie's answer. You can avoid the first few steps. Just type "Manage user certificates" in windows search bar. Go to Personal > Certificates. 
Your certificates would have Issued to "Windows Azure Tools".

You can check for the thumbprint by opening the certificate and checking the Details.